# iOS development with Whited00r 7

Tags: ios, development

I am an iOS developer, and have an old 3G device. If I setup whited00r 7, can I use that device for development as I can use a device with iOS 7? (Register provisioning profile for that device and install ipa on it?) Are there any restrictions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. whited00r uses a [heavily customized version of iOS 3.1.3 and 4.2.1](http://www.whited00r.com/about?lang=en).  They've tweaked the OS to look like iOS 7 and provide similar functionality.  They cannot backport Apple's proprietary and copyrighted iOS 7 APIs to older devices.

Additionally, the [latest version of Xcode requires ARMv7 devices](http://www.cocoanetics.com/2012/08/softly-killing-iphone-3g/), which does not include any of the devices supported by whited00r.

You must have a [device that can actually run iOS 7](http://www.apple.com/ios/features/#compatibility-footer) if you want to develop apps on the device.